# Actualizar DB de wordpress despues de actualizar plugins

Tags: php, base-de-datos, wordpress

me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de actualizar la DB despues de actualizar mis plugins en mi wordpress local. Paso los archivos de mi sitio local al sitio en linea y quiero actualizar la DB del sitio en linea con los nuevoss plugins.

Segun yo hay una URL especial para actualizar la DB para este tipo de cosas, agradeceria que me la pasaran si saben cual es.

Answer (score 1):

No es tan fácil opinar en este sentido ya que desconozco el uso de esa base de datos.
Tan sólo lo veo normal querer hacer eso si la página está en construcción.
En ese caso la palabra clave es MIGRACION DE BASE DE DATOS EN MYSQL, no tiene nada que ver con el WP.

Para ello, y siempre y cuando no corras riesgos con el sitio online por ejemplo de borrar datos de usuarios y otros aspectos que no tengas en tu WP local, los pasos serían los siguientes. POR FAVOR TEN EN CUENTA QUE SE VAN A BORRAR TODOS LOS DATOS. No solamente los plugins, sino también las paginas, entradas y mucho más.

1.- Abres PHPMyAdmin, poninedo en el navegador http://localhost
2.- pinchas en la Base de datos concreta donde esté tu WP.
3.- Busca la opción de EXPORTAR arriba por el centro más o menos (no me acuerdo de memoria)
4.- Prueba primero con las opciones por defecto y le das a guardar.
Guardas el fichero *.sql poniendole un nombre  a tu gusto y luego lo contrario

Vas a la Base de datos online y le das a truncar todas las tablas.
LA BASE DE DATOS VA A BORRARSE ENTERA.

Luego le das a importar y metes de fuente el fichero *.sql que habias generado antes.

Al acabar tienes que ir a la tabla wp_options y cambiar el valor de site_url y de home_url por el nombre del dominio donde tienes alojado el WP online con la extensión que tenga en internet tu dominio.

Además, luego tienes que acceder a la administración de WP, y en **Ajustes > Enlaces permanentes** tienes que darle a guardar sin hacer nada, o bien cambiar de opción, darle a guardar y volver a poner la opción que tenias y darle a guardar de nuevo.

Aún siguiendo todas mis indicaciones, es muy posible que algunos elementos dejen de funcionar porque tengan los enlaces apuntando al sitio local. y tendras que cambiar esos enlaces a mano.

Suerte. ya nos comentas.